# JQuery Mobile Problems With Input Type File

Tags: jquery-mobile, file-upload, input

So I want to use a document upload element in a web form using JQuery Mobile. Every mobile platform in my testing environment allows it, (only small additional styling is allowed but some none the less) until I come to IE and IE Mobile. It is all scew-whiff in both and doesn't function at all in IE Mobile.

Am I missing some secret documentation or am I being stupid expecting IE to behave like others... I am going to guess that yet again, they are laughing in the face of conformity.

Thank you for any input and advice.

In regards to code, I am not using anything fancier then:

```
<input name="exampleName" class="exampleClass" id="exampleDocument" type="file" size="250" value=""/>

<!--and Jquery Mobile changes the class name to input ui-input-text ui-body-a-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE for Windows Phone 7/8 as like iOS 5 and lower don't support file upload from web browser. [File Upload Support](http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/file-upload-support-on-mobile/)

Comment: Thank you, quite shocked with MS, a brand new operating system on their mobile devices and they dont even allow it feedback to tell the user it is not supported, you are left just clicking with no response! Oh well, it just mean I cant support the 17 global Win phone users (; Thank you#